# Application launch in blue prism

Tags: blueprism

I am trying to launch an windows application. I have given executable path. Whenever I click on launch, it’s not changing to Identify. It’s coming back to Launch. So what could be the issue?

Comment: Do you observe the application being successfully launched?

Comment: Yes. The application was launching. It’s not changing to Identify. It’s still coming back to Launch.

Answer (score 1):

When the application is successfully launched, but the button does not change from "Launch" to "Detach", it's usually an issue with how you've targeted your window's title.

Usually, appending wildcards to the ends of the window's title will assist in matching correctly. Additionally, ensure that the "Windows process name" field is completed correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is common for windows applications that are trigger points like RDP, MMC.  You would have to have an attach after the launch to gain the connection for identify to become enabled.