# error in launching application windows

Tags: launch, blueprism

I tried to launch/attach "mmc.exe" in bluePrism but it doesn't work. Is there any solution?

[image]

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51089877/1578604) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the blue prism as 'administrator' and then try doing a launch or attach.